# In Pathfinder, how are scroll creation costs calculated?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

The Pathfinder SRD states that "*The cost to create a scroll is half the base price.*"

But it also says that "*a character needs a supply of choice writing materials, the cost of which is subsumed in the cost for scribing the scroll: 12.5 gp × the level of the spell × the level of the caster*".

What if the `12.5 * spell level * caster level` is greater than `base price / 2`? Is the cost the maximum of the two? Or is the cost of the choice materials always subsumed in the overall cost?

As an example, if a level 10 cleric creates a scroll of a level 2 spell, is the cost `75gp` (half the base price) or `250gp` (12.5 * 2 * 10)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The base price, in this case, expects the scroll is created at the **minimum caster level** required.
Hence 75GP given by (12.5 * 2 * 3)

This is also why scroll costs vary by who scribes them.

You can choose to create a scroll at lower than your total caster level, if you want, or you can use your full caster level to gain greater effects (such as extra magic missiles).

The scroll's caster level is also used for effects such as Spell Resistance and resisting Dispel Magic.
If (for whatever) reason the spell refers to the casting stat of the person casting it (for instance a Wizard's Int), the lowest needed to cast the spell is used. (e.g. a 2nd level spell requires 12 in the stat, thus the modifier would be +1)

Comment: Ah I see. So a scroll technically is specified by a casting level as well as the spell, and a CL10 fireball scroll is different from a CL5 one (but the default is the minimum). Got it.

Comment: Yep. Most magic items work that way, very few use the wielder's level (it's part of the reason staves are so pricey!).

Comment: Note that the caster level of a not only determines how powerful the scroll's effects are but also how difficult it is do destroy with Dispel Magic.

Comment: Added that. Need to find the citation for the minimum stat bit, it's in the magic chapter (not magic items) iirc.

Comment: @oli Do be aware that because of the multiplicative effect, it is *very* rarely price-effective to make scrolls with higher caster levels.

Answer (score 4):

The caster level is actually the caster level on which you want to cast that spell.
The scroll prices are calculated for a scroll with minimum required caster level.
For a level 2 spell that would be level 3.

```
12.5 * 2 * 3 = 75gp
```

> Table: Scrolls gives sample prices for scrolls created at the lowest
>   possible caster level for each spellcasting class

You can however scribe a scroll with a higher caster level (up to your CL) to make the spell stronger.

A cure moderate wounds scroll with CL3 would heal 2D8+3 Hitpoints. With CL10 it would heal 2D8+10 HP.